# aiimage image name call python

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to get the image name path from an Arnold aiImage node in Maya.

```
import pymel.core as pm

shaders=pm.ls(sl=True)
for e in shaders:
    string=pm.getAttr(e+'.fileTextureName')
```

The maya method uses fileTextureName, but that's not the way to call upon the Arnold file node path apparently. I can't seem to find any reference or doc on it online.

Any Ideas?

Comment: generically you can try listAttr on the nodes and find out what Arnold calls things.  Saving an MA file and snooping through it by text is often the fastest way to figure these things out

Comment: The fastest way is probably to set the desired attribute and inspect the Script Editor that shows the respective "setAttr" mel command together with the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the attribute is called 'filename'
It didn't show up in callbacks but a friend at work happened to know.